# Memory out of Exception while creating Bitmap from MemoryStream in WinCE Device

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-ce, memorystream

```
using (MemoryStream ms = imager.CaptureImageNow().MemoryStream ) 
{
   using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms)) // Memory Out of Exception occurs here
   {
           this.PreviewImage( bmp );

   }
}
```

Hi ,i am using WinCE device platform 3.5 and getting memory out of exception while creating Bitmap. my Image format is JPEG. Is there any other way to avoid this exception.

Comment: not enough information

Comment: how to avoid the exception: use less memory in your program, free memory from unused stuff, add more memory to the machine.

Comment: can you post the exception? preferably with stack trace.

Comment: What you are currently posting is a random snippet of code that might not even be the problem: can you give us a little more?

Comment: How large (hxw) and what pixel depth is the picture you're trying to load?  My bet is that your device doesn't have enough memory to hold it.

Answer (score 0):

I already have this problem, try this :

```
byte[] imgDatas = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = imager.CaptureImageNow().MemoryStream ) 
{
    imgDatas = ms.GetBuffer();
}

ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
Image img = (Image)ic.ConvertFrom(imgDatas);

using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img))
{
    this.PreviewImage( bmp );
}
```

Comment: Hi, ImageConverter is not available as my device has WinCE 3.5 platform

Comment: Ok, so try to use an intermediate MemoryStream loaded with the GetBuffer of the first memoryStream

Comment: "bei Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar)\r\nbei System.Drawing.Bitmap._InitFromMemoryStream(MemoryStream mstream)\r\nbei System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)\r\nbei\r\nbei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)\r\nbei

Comment: Hi,I tried another intermediate memorystream but problem is occuring still, above is the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
byte[] imgDatas = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = imager.CaptureImageNow().MemoryStream ) 
{
    imgDatas = ms.GetBuffer();
}

MemoryStream msImg = new MemoryStream(imgDatas);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(msImg);
msImg.Dispose();

PreviewImage(bmp);
```